# error when splitting full name into first name and last name

Tags: sql, sql-server

When running the below code, I get an error of Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

The names are in the format:

LastName FirstName MiddleName

Only the last name and first name are relevant to me

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(longname, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', longname + ' ') - 1) AS Firstname,     
       SUBSTRING(longname,
                 CHARINDEX(' ', longname + ' ') + 1,
                 LEN(longname) - CHARINDEX(' ', longname + ' ')) AS Lastname
FROM Table 
WHERE longname IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Input and expected output ?

Comment: I love this article, because it's completely true: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). TL;DR: If the name isn't split already, you have no full-proof way of finding out what the first name and last name *really* are, without asking the person themselves or someone who personally knows them.

Comment: "longname" doesn't contain space , so its throwing "Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function."  Please the "longname" value or keep condition so if space contain apply the substring function else take longname as firstname

Comment: @asimshahiddIT there will always be a space as I'm adding a space. Please see the example above.

Comment: please send some data related to longname

Comment: Maybe this would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns . Also, if you are doing this a lot of times, creating a split function does help in the longer run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the logic for `LastName` is off.  Try this:

```
SELECT v.Firstname,     
       LEFT(rest, CHARINDEX(' ', rest + ' ') - 1) as LastName
FROM Table t CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (LEFT(longname, CHARINDEX(' ', longname + ' ') - 1),
              STUFF(longname, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', longname + ' '), '')
             )
     ) v(FirstName, rest)
WHERE longname IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for the response. I'm receiving an error of Incorrect syntax near 'STUFF'.

Comment: I *think* Gordon meant there to be comma after `) - 1)`, @Fler , as they define the `VALUES` constructor as returning 2 columns, and the `LEFT` function is closed at that point.

Answer (score 0):

"longname" doesn't contain space , so its throwing "Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function."  Please the "longname" value or keep condition so if space contain apply the substring function else take longname as firstname

Comment: there will always be a space as I'm adding a space. Please see the example above.